# Azure Key Vault secrets value reading from Angular Code

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I have some secret key which is presently in the git repo of angular code, which is not secure - I want them to be read from the Azure key vault from angular code.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: If you read the Key Vault secret to your Angular front-end, it will be visible to users of your app, is that ok? Of course you can do the read by authenticating the user with Azure AD and then reading it on their behalf (meaning the user had read access anyway).

Comment: Is there any sample you have that shows how to read it from angular code?

Answer (score 0):

Managed identities are helpful to allows your app to easily access other Azure AD-protected resources such as Azure Key Vault

Please try below steps to access Key Vault

1. Create Managed identity in Azure and Add role assignment to read Key Vault
2. If your application is deployed in Azure App Service, go to Settings --> Identity --> User Assigned.
3. Add the identity created earlier in step 1

If the application in deployed in Azure VM, managed identity can be added to VM. Please refer to the documentation for more details on managed identity

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp

Comment: Yes, our backend api is already fetching it from azure key vault by managed identity in AD.

Comment: Looking for Angular code sample - which can read the vault value

Comment: Please find the sample here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets